# Using background image in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I cannot seem to get rails to recognize an image that I need to use for a background. The last thing I tried was to rename my css file layout.css.scss to layout.css.scss.erb so the asset_path helper could be used, but it does not work. The image is located in the app/assets/images directory. layout.css.scss.erb is located in the app/assets/stylesheets directory. The css styling is:  background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'Jolie2.jpg' %>); It is located near the end of the layout.css.scss.erb file. I am posting the whole file as well as the partial that displays the image. Please help.

```css
// layouts.css.scss.erb

@import "colors";
header#page-header {
  font-family:'Lobster', cursive;
  color: $secondary-color;
  background: $primary-color;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
}

footer#page-footer {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center; 
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px; 
  color: $secondary-color;
  background: $primary-color; 
}

aside#page-sidebar 
{
  a:link 
  {
    color: black;
  }
  a:visited
  {
    color: black;
  }
  a:hover
  {
    color:#FFA68F;
  }
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right; 
  background: $primary-color; 
  width: 244px;
}
aside.image
{
  background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'Jolie2.jpg' %>);
  width: 244px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  clear: both;
  float: right;
}

// _jolie.html.erb

<aside class="image">

</aside>
```

`

Comment: I am so glad it is working for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by specifying the css height: attribute. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

it should work:

1. Are you using up-to-date gems sass-rails and sprockets?
2. Try to  rename .css.scss to .scss
3. Try to replace  image-path('Jolie2.jpg') with
   asset-url('Jolie2.jpg', image)  or image-url('Jolie2.jpg')

Comment: I did not have 'sprocket-rails' in my gem file. I put it in, ran bundle install and tried your suggestions but no luck. Here is my gemfile:           source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.9'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development